# F# equivalent to Scala lazy val with case class/discriminated union

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

In Scala I can do something like this:

```scala
abstract class MyData
case class A() extends MyData
case class B() extends MyData

implicit class HeavyComputationProvider(val data : MyData) {
    private def _HeavyComputation() = /* */;
    lazy val HeavyComputation = this._HeavyComputation();
}

// Example usage:
val a = A
println a.HeavyComputation // This will calculate
println a.HeavyComputation // This will use the cached value
```

This has the benefit of caching when re-used, but not calculated when not used.

How do you do provide the lazy `HeavyComputation` for the following F# type?

```
type MyData =
    | A
    | B

type MyData with
    member private this.__HeavyComputation = (* *)

    // Error: This declaration element is not permitted in an augmentation and this is unavailable
    let _HeavyComputation = lazy((* *))
    // This will just create a *new* lazy computation each time
    member this._HeavyComputation = lazy(this.__HeavyComputation)
    // This should lazily compute & cache, transparent to the caller
    member this.HeavyComputation = this._HeavyComputation.Force
```

Comment: See http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/59072

Comment: @AlexG Thanks, that partly solves the problem, but unfortunatly `this` is unavailable in `let`, I've augmented the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no direct equivalent of the Scala approach. Doing this requires keeping some additional state as part of the object (e.g. a lazy value) and F# does not let you add additional state to objects once they are defined.

The closest thing you can do is to write a wrapper type that stores the original `MyData` value together with the additional lazy computation:

```
type MyData =
    | A
    | B

type MyDataWithComputation(data:MyData) =
  let _HeavyComputation = lazy(1)
  member this.MyData = data
  member this.HeavyComputation = _HeavyComputation.Value
```

And then use it as follows:

```
let myd = MyDataWithComputation(A)
myd.HeavyComputation 
myd.HeavyComputation
```